# Can't access EC2 through public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have set up a VPC and created an EC2 instance in one of its public subnets. The user data of the instance has the simple code below. When I connect to the instance, all I get it the screen shot below. it should be a web page that says hello world. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I am too new to embed images so Stackoverflow gave me a link to my image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGqcY.png
This is what I get when I go to the public IP address via my browser:
[Chrome snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl06h.png)

EDIT: What I am trying to do is to access the website through the public IP but it won't connect. Also see this "refused to connect" from the shell:[Refused to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPURV.png)

EDIT2: also from the shell when I try to get relevant IPs. What does this mean? [Specify Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4BKP.png)

Edit3: [curl localhost connection refused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MguK.png)

Edit4: [Inbound SG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsBZ9.png) [Outbound SG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1IDk.png)

```
# #!/bin/bash

#Use this for your user data (script from top to bottom)

#install httpd (Linux 2 version)

yum update -y

yum install -y httpd

systemctl start httpd

systemctl enable httpd

echo "<h1>Hello World from $(hostname -f)</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

I have made sure public subnet is associated with a routing table where the destination is 0.0.0.0/0 and the target is an IGW.

The SG allows all HTTP and HTTPS traffic from IPv4 and IPv6.

ACL allows all outbound and inbound traffic and all subnets are associated with it.

Comment: What screenshot? You haven't provided any.

Comment: I am too new to embed images so Stackoverflow gave me a link to my image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGqcY.png

Comment: "When I connect to the instance, all I get it the screen shot below. it should be a web page that says hello world." - When you connect to the instance, that's exactly what you see, the shell. What happens when you visit the instances IP?

Comment: This is what I get when I go to the public IP address via my browser:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl06h.png @Jordan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your webserver is not running (based on the rejection you get when doing `curl` from the box)

To investigate try this

`sudo cat /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001` -- this should show you your user data script -- if not, then you have somehow misconfigured the user data

`sudo cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log` to see the log of what happened when your user data script ran. If you see errors in here, then you will need to debug and correct your user data

Also as part of debugging, you can try running the same commands in your user data from the command line, and see if you get a working web server (see if `curl` works). You probably need to `sudo su` before running these from the command line

Please note, that if you change the user data, it does *not* take effect on an already running EC2 instance.  User data is only run when the EC2 server is initially launched.

Comment: Thank for the feedback Seth. I will get started on that but my first question is about you saying "if you change the user data, it does not take effect on an already running EC2 instance. User data is only run when the EC2 server is initially launched." So if I stop the instance, go to actions, edit user data, then restart the instance, then the user data DOESNT change?

Comment: That is correct.  You can however get fancy and set it up to run with every restart: 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/ -- but I would not suggest messing with the user data file like that until you nail down the problem you have here

Comment: I already went in a changed stopped the instance and changed the user data to an entirely different script. This is what I was starting with from the AWS solutions architect course:

Comment: ~~~#!/bin/bash -ex

# Update yum
yum - y update

#Add node’s source repo
curl -sL  https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_15x | bash - 

#install nodejs
yum -y install nodejs

#create a dedicated directory for the application
mkdir -p /var/app

#get the app from s3
wget https://aws-tc-largeobjects.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ILT-TF-100-TECESS-5/app/app.zip

#extract it to the desired folder
unzip app.zip -d /var/app/
cd /var/app/

#install dependencies
npm install

#start the app
npm start~~~

Comment: It looks like I was able to create a file with the Hello world in it. I am still unable to connect the instance through the public IP

Comment: are you saying `curl localhost` works then?  If so, and you have the webserver running on the instance, and you still cannot access through the public IP, then it is a networking issues.  Check both the Security Group(s) and the NACLs that apply to this EC2 instance.